# hacer que un textbox dependa de lo que se seleccione en un combobox C#

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox, textbox

buenas noches a todos estoy tratando de hacer que en un textbox se imprima un dato ejemplo

tengo la tabla producto de la cual hago click en el combobox y me manda llamar los datos de una tabla de mysql

pero quiero que cuando mande llamar la columna descripcion en el combobox y seleccione un registro me mande llamar el ID, la cantidad y otras cosas mas. producto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que estoy usando para llenar el combobox

```
    //metodo para llamar comobobox nombre del metodo combo1
    public void Llenarcombo(ComboBox combo1)
    {
        string query = "SELECT `descripcion` FROM `productos`";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,obternerconexion());
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        combo1.ValueMember = "id";
        combo1.DisplayMember = "descripcion";
        combo1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

y bueno logre hacer que en el textbox de codigo corto me imprimiera lo siguiente.  adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se preguntaran como logre ese pues usando la el siguiente codigo.

```
private void combo1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtcocorto.Text = combo1productods.Text; 

    }
```

use la porpiedad SelectedIndexChanged  del combobox. deseo que en dode dice codigo corto me imprima el codigo corto del producto, alguien podra ayudarme y mas importante podre usar este metodo para lo que nesecito SelectedIndexChanged,,,, y como seria?

de ante mano muchas gracias por su ayuda...

Answer (score 0):

Esta bien el codigo solo falta mostrar en la consulta el id, por que solo esta la descripcion

```
string query = "SELECT `id`,`descripcion` FROM `productos`";
```

y con eso al momento de activarse el evento `combo1_SelectedIndexChanged` obtienes el id mediante el `selectValue` y ese id lo mandas por parametro en una nueva consulta para obtener los datos de ese producto.

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar los datos segun la seleccion del combo debes aplicar un filtro

```
private void combo1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(combo1productods.SelectedValue); 

    string query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Id = @id";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, obternerconexion());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(reader.Read())
    {
        txtId.Text = reader["Id"].ToString();
        //otros campos
        txtCantidad.Text = reader["cantidad"].ToString();
    }

}
```

Observa como se asigna el parametros que influira en el `WHERE` para obtener los campos de la tabla en base a la seleccion

---

Otro problema que observo es que defines la consulta

```
string query = "SELECT `descripcion` FROM `productos`";
```

Pero no esta el campo `id` que asignas en

```
combo1.ValueMember = "id";
```

esto es importante para poder usar el `SelectedValue`, agrega ese campo en el select